# Is the OpenGeo Suite available via Docker?

Tags: boundless-suite, administration, docker

Given that many GIS apps such as [GeoServer](https://hub.docker.com/r/kartoza/geoserver/) & [PostGIS](https://hub.docker.com/r/kartoza/postgis/) are available as docker images, has anyone made a OpenGeo Suite Docker Image?

I'm searching for this, since the [installation page for OpenGeo](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/intro/installation/ubuntu/index.html), says that it should not be installed on the same system as Qgis, since there will be a conflict.

This looks like a perfect use-case for Docker.

Is the OpenGeo Suite Available as a Docker Image?

Answer (score 1):

I have myself created a Docker Image, which is available here: https://hub.docker.com/r/devdattat/docker-opengeosuite/

This is based on a Dockerfile, which can be accessed here: https://github.com/devdattaT/docker-OpenGeoSuite/blob/master/Dockerfile